# Custom added images disappear after rendering

Tags: image

I'm a complete beginner to Blender and I'm sorry if this is such an easy problem to fix, I just can't figure it out.

So I made a monitor model for my game (Using Unreal). I add a fake samsung logo image and my desktop screenshot to the screen of my monitor model, just to make it look a bit more like a real monitor.

But after rendering, these 2 images disappear and I can't see them in Unreal too. What could be the problem?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hello, unitylearns, and welcome. Please give enough detail for us to help you. You could [add an image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) showing your material / UV map... tell us how you are exporting your model.

Answer (score 0):

Alright found it.

Basically, just create a plane and create a material for it. Click the little dot next to "Base Color" and choose "Image Texture". Select your image. This fixed my problem.